# JPGraph bottom margin with Legend on/off

Tags: php, margin, legend, jpgraph

I have a problem with PHP Graphing library at JPGraph.net .
I have a really simple LinePlot() and if i add a legend to the graph the bottom margin of the graph extend by circa 10 pixels. Making the graph legend Show() or Hide() doesn't make any difference the bottom margin is added to the graph right after the legend is associated with a lineplot.

Is there any solution to switch off this behaviour? Because i generate thumbnail size graphs (eg. 180x100) the bottom margin white area is quite "large".

For better understanding:

Left: starting point before legend is added

Right: After the legend is added, no other changes to the margins/code of the graph

Oops i dont have enough reputation to post images :(

[left_good](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21432785/jpgraph/fixgraph.png)
[right_bad](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21432785/jpgraph/fixgraph_wrong.png)

Answer (score 13):

The solution for this problem is add:

$graph->graph_theme=null;

just before the:

$graph->Stroke();

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the legend is more or less independent from the graph itself, it can be placed anywhere.

The margin of the graph itself can - in most cases - be modified using...

```
Graph::SetMargin($left_m, $right_m, $top_m, $bottom_m)
```

...(margin in pixels) which could look like this in your code:

```
$graph = new Graph(180,100);    
$graph->SetMargin(10,20,30,40);

/* followed by alot more code for your graph until... */
$graph->Stroke();
```

I advise looking into the extensive documentation which is included in the JPGraph packages, the classes are well documented and they offer alot of examples how to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I can concur with Bjorn that $graph->SetMargin(lMargin,rMargin,tMargin,bMargin); is the way to go. However, on my line plot setting the bottom margin doesn't appear to have any effect. In know there is a footer, and like the legend, populating this -- or not -- also has no effect on the bottom margin. If you stumble on anything like this I'd be really grateful to know how you solve it.

Best of luck,
C

Comment: Same here @Chris . The bottom margin have no efect on the graph. There must be some coordinates recomputed if the Legend is added in the graph and then bottom margin doesn't work as expected. I will look in the source code what is going on, but doesn't know what to search for. I look at jpgraph_legend.inc.php and there doesn't seem to be anything that could change the graph margin in any way :(

Answer (score 0):

This margin is set in jpgraph_legend.inc.php on line 35.

```
private $ybottom_margin = 8;
```

This value cannot be changed by a method, it's a hard-coded margin which you can only change there.

But you can add a new method to the legend class:

```
function SetYBottomMargin($aYMarg) {
    $this->ybottom_margin = $aYMarg;
}
```

Call it like *$graph->legend->SetYBottomMargin(0);* to set the bottom margin to 0.

Comment: I don't know how to actually fix this, but changing code of 3rd party libraries is strongly discouraged as it makes it very difficult to upgrade unless you conduct very good documentary about every single line you have changed.